# Meaning of "would" here? Could someone please elaborate this?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

"You'd get through the interview,"  I wish everyone would stop telling me that.
What does it mean here?  A few more examples would be more helpful.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Is the sentence "I wish..." part of the question? Part of the quote? And which **would** are you asking about? You would get... or .... would stop telling me...?

Comment: Wish everyone would stop telling me that.  This part is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means that the person is tired of hearing this same observation.

I want everyone to stop telling me that.

> Expressing a conjecture, opinion, or hope.
>
> ‘I would imagine that they're home by now’
>
> ‘I guess some people would consider it brutal’
>
> ‘I would have to agree’

OED